# FitNesse configuration files

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, fitnesse

I'm using FitNesse as a functional testing framework. I'm running into trouble when FitNesse runs code that needs configuration.

If I need to get a connection string from the configuration file, I can get it to work by adding it to the FitServer.exe.config. However, I don't like that solution. I would like FitNesse to load my own configuration file, namely TheNameOfMyApp.dll.config.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, easy to do. I'm assuming you're using the dotnet or dotnet2 test runner. I'm using the dotnet2 test runner, and here's how I've got it set up:

First, when you !define your COMMAND_PATTERN, include -c suite.config. For instance, I have the following in root:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -c suite.config %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {..\..\bin\Debug\FitServer.exe}
```

suite.config goes in the same dir as fitnesse.jar:

```
<suiteConfig>
    <fit.Settings>
        <appConfigFile>..\..\MyProjectFolder\fitnesse\MyProjectName.config</appConfigFile>
    </fit.Settings>
    <fit.Assemblies>
    </fit.Assemblies>
    <fit.FileExclusions>
        <add>^\.svn$</add>
    </fit.FileExclusions>
    <fit.Namespaces>
    </fit.Namespaces>
    <fit.CellHandlers>
    </fit.CellHandlers>
    <fitlibrary.CellHandlers>
    </fitlibrary.CellHandlers>
</suiteConfig>
```

MyProjectName.config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="keyname" value="something" />
    </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

You can make things easier for yourself if you use an absolute path for the appConfigFile. I started off with an absolute path, got things working, then switched to a relative path by trial and error.

Note that I'm running my test runner from a non-standard location, which will affect the relative path in suite.config. The path is relative to your TEST_RUNNER location, NOT to suite.config or fitnesse.jar.

Comment: Although this works, you can also use the -a option (instead of the -c option) as noted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849172/fitnesse-app-config - just a little bit more simple

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible but an awful load of work. you need to define a test-project where you have your tests in it and a "wrapper"-project where you have the functionality of providing the tests with data and configuration settings.

Comment: Do you have a link to an example solution or tutorial?