# FitNesse App.Config

Tags: .net, testing, fitnesse, fitsharp

I am having a hard time understanding: http://www.syterra.com/Fit/AppConfigFiles.html

If my application and fixtures are in c:\Projects\App and FitNesse is running from c:\Projects\Sandbox\FitNesse

I am assuming c:\mypath\myapp.exe.config would be c:\Projects\App[MyFixtureAssmbly].config, but I am unsure of what c:\myfolder\mysuite.config.xml is?

I have tried putting it in the fitSharp folder with Runner.exe.config, fit.dll.config, with .xml after those names, in the FitNesse root folder, in the App directory.. I just can't figure out where to put it so it will load my app.config?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FitNesse configuration files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654259/fitnesse-configuration-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example c:\myfolder\mysuite.config.xml is a suite configuration file ( see http://fitsharp.github.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html ).  This is optional and provides a way to externalize 'techno' configuration information from the test pages.

If you are not using one, you can still use the -a switch.

Comment: Ahh, on the fitSharp site it makes it seem like you need to use the -a switch. I will have to write you some new manuals or a wiki jediwhale! ;)

Getting it to work with iBatis wasn't as hard as i had thought at first either! Thanks for the help!

Comment: by -a switch i meant -c switch ;)

Comment: Yes, I work on the documentation a little bit when I have time but still lots more to do!

Answer (score 0):

[NetRunner](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner) uses configuration file for the first dll from the list.

For exampple, for the line:

```
!path C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld1.dll, C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld2.dll
```

NetRunner will use configuration file "C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld1.dll.config"